# Different result of getting value string representation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm continue to experimenting with the name value pair of `JS` objects. **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/BYwz9/6/)**

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <div id="child" class="child">
        <input type="text" class="text"/>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="doThis()"/>
    </div>
<div>
```

and `JS` code

```
function doThis(){
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    var parent=document.getElementById("parent");
    var child=document.getElementById("child");
    var submit=document.getElementById("submit");
    child.insertBefore(span,submit);
    myKeys=[];
    for(var key in submit){
        if(key=="parentNode"){
            myKeys.push("{"+key);
            myKeys.push(" "+submit.key+"}");
        }
    }  
    myKeys.push("{"+"parentNode");
    myKeys.push(" "+submit.parentNode+"}");
    span.innerHTML=myKeys;
}
```

Just created `span` contains the following:

```
{parentNode, undefined},{parentNode, [object HTMLDivElement]}
```

But i'm expected that this `span` will be contained `{parentNode, [object HTMLDivElement]},{parentNode, [object HTMLDivElement]}`. Please, explain me why it's occured?

Updated: I changed the link to actual.

Comment: What exactly is your question? what are you trying to do? Is the span inserted at a wrong place?

Comment: @Samy I'm trying to realize why the code snippet `for(var key in submit){ if(key=="parentNode"){ myKeys.push("{"+key); myKeys.push(" "+submit.key+"}");}}` added to `myKeys` `{parentNode, undefined}` rather than `{parentNode, [object HTMLDivElement]}` as it was added by the `myKeys.push("{"+"parentNode");
    myKeys.push(" "+submit.parentNode+"}");
    span.innerHTML=myKeys;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 submit.key
```

you are accessing to the property **key** of the Node Object and in this case there is no property with name **key**.

If you want to access to the property **parentNode** you have to do:

```
submit[key]
```

in this case the value of the variable **key** is used as name of the property in the Node Object that you want to access. (parentNode)

Anyway, the standard way is to do:

```
document.getElementById("submit").parentNode;
```

or use a library to easily manipulate DOM elements (see http://jquery.com/)